# For Loop List Python for Variable URL

Tags: python, string, list, loops, url

So if I wanted to print the contents of a url page or just cycle through many and only change a few segments of the URL how might I do so. Given the following:

If I know the format will usually be the following for any player, minus a few tweeks to the ID and last portion:
Format below:

```
http://espn.go.com/mlb/player/_/id/31000/brad-brach
```

Lets say I know each players ID and name:

```
PLAYER_NAME = ['brad-brach','oliver-drake',...]
PLAYER_ID = ['31000','31615',...]
for i in PLAYER_ID:
url = 'http://espn.go.com/mlb/player/_/id/'+PLAYER_ID[i]+/'+PLAYER_NAME[i]
```

Do what ever given that we know all these players in the PLAYER_ID and PLAYER_NAME.

How might I iterate through all the PLAYER_ID's and PLAYER_NAME's without getting a

> TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str

I know that url is a list and the contents within it PLAYER_ID[0] would be a string. What am I missing here?

Comment: for player in PLAYER_NAME: is what you're looking for

Comment: Now place player in your url string. Not PLAYER_ID that is a list

Comment: You're adding lists (player_id and player_name) to a string (url)

Comment: `PLAYER_NAMES` and `PLAYER_IDS` would be better names for collections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select an item from list by index not the string of another list, PLAYER_NAME['31000']?!

```
PLAYER_NAME = ['brad-brach','oliver-drake',...]
PLAYER_ID = ['31000','31615',...]
for i in xrange(len(PLAYER_NAME)):
    url = 'http://espn.go.com/mlb/player/_/id/{}/{}'.format(PLAYER_ID[i], PLAYER_NAME[i])
```

And for an even more elegant solution use zip, thanks to @Pynchia ;)

```
PLAYER_NAME = ['brad-brach','oliver-drake',...]
PLAYER_ID = ['31000','31615',...]
URL_PATTERN = 'http://espn.go.com/mlb/player/_/id/{}/{}'
for p_name, p_id in zip(PLAYER_NAME, PLAYER_ID):
    url = URL_PATTERN.format(p_id, p_name)
```

Comment: I believe that this is closest to what OP wants...kind of hard to tell from their question, though.

Comment: So I was kind of close

Comment: get the glory, I was just pulling your leg. :)

Comment: fix it and add the version with `zip` to make your answer more complete

Comment: "OP" = "Original Post[er]"

Answer (score 0):

`for something in container` will give you each item in the container; this is a very clean way of iterating:

```
>>> for i in PLAYER_ID:
...     print i
31000
31615
```

When you use `PLAYER_ID[i]`, what you really want is the index. You can get that by enumerating every element in the list:

```
>>> for i, element in enumerate(PLAYER_ID):
...     print i, element
0 31000
1 31615
```

However, you don't really need the index, as you already have a clean way of getting the player's ID.

As I mentioned in a comment, better names would be `PLAYER_IDS` and `PLAYER_NAMES`, so that:

```
>>> for PLAYER_NAME, PLAYER_ID in zip(PLAYER_NAMES, PLAYER_IDS):
...     print PLAYER_NAME, PLAYER_ID
brad-brach 31000
oliver-drake 31615
```

Comment: So in order to print the stats of these players, I would need to for-loop to execute both players stats. I would need to read the customized url. So it would read on the first iteration: url: http://espn.go.com/mlb/player/_/id/31000/brad-brach then on the second iteration url would be http://espn.go.com/mlb/player/_/id/31615/oliver-drake

Comment: @RossJohnson Hey, those urls actually work! Nice job.

Comment: Ah ha! Got it! Thank you!